# How to write "1st-order"

Tags: conjunctions, spelling

Consider a sentence like:

> A first-order language.

I am interested in the correct spelling of "first-order" in this context while writing "first" with a number. Which of the following would be correct?

> A 1st-order language.
> A 1'st-order language.
> A 1-st-order language.

Or should I ommit the dash in front of "order" as well, so:

> A 1st order language.
> A 1'st order language.
> A 1-st order language.

Which version i correct spelling, if any?

Comment: Conventionally, we (1) write cardinal and ordinal numbers lower than some limit, often 11, in words and (2) hyphenate compound adjectives when they are before the noun they modify, so **first-order language**.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Alright, thank you for your comment. How would you write it with a number in case of "twelve-order language"?

Comment: 12th-order language, e.g. _The 12th-Order Differential Attack on the 10-Round Variants of Midori64 Block Cipher_ (paper title, hence capitals), _the 12th-order polynomial approximation to the probability density function of ρ for two independent Wiener processes_ and _the 12th-order polynomial fit to the spectral passband utilised in the published study leads to spurious results_ (Google is your friend)

Comment: The hyphen is usual, but not obligatory.

Answer (score 2):

These are style questions, so usages might vary. Often academic or professional writing places, like universities or newspapers, will have their own "style guide" that will say exactly what you should do. But I can talk about what *many* such guides say.

Most style guides encourage you to spell out these numbers when they're small, but recognize that something like "one million three hundred seventy-two thousand four hundred fifty sixth" is impractical. [The Australian government](https://www.stylemanual.gov.au/grammar-punctuation-and-conventions/numbers-and-measurements/ordinal-numbers) style guide says to use numerals for "10th" and above; [Chicago](https://nps.edu/documents/111693070/112865214/infographic+numbers+CMOSv3.pdf/2b44c7f6-8c0a-3a69-9efc-863e2bf90ec1?t=1584036528790) says "101st" and higher. Most would agree that "first" is better spelled out.

For the style of numeric representations like "1st," I don't think any style guide would recommend adding an apostrophe (*1'st*) or hyphen within the abbreviation (*1-st*). Chicago Manual also notes that the "st" should *not* be superscript (*1<sup>st</sup>*), though others might prefer it.

For formal writing, using hyphens within adjectival phrases is best. I would also argue that it's important and good even in informal writing, as it can help avoid misunderstanding, but you might see it omitted often.

Answer (score 1):

The 'correct' spelling is "first-order". It is less than ideal to use a numeral.

If you use a numeral you can write it as 1st or 1<sup>st</sup>.

You probably should not omit the hyphen,  so "1<sup>st</sup>-order".  But since you are already "wrong" for using a numeral it doesn't much matter.  And actual usage is quite free, with "1st-order" and "1st order" both being common.